# javascript get day name for two years later from today

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying get name of the day of the week like "Wednesday" 2 years and 30 days later from now.

i am stuck here, and i already tried :

```
var ts=(new Date()).getDay();
console.log(new Date(ts));
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: All you are asking is how to add two dates together and then how to use a date formatter string. NEVER write your own date displays like the 3 answers so far are doing. Always translate a DateTime() using a formatter, and store all dates in UTC or something consistent.

Comment: The reason you never use your own enum is for locale differences and maintenance. Look at the Non-accepted answers here to find out the right way, the accepted answer is a nightmare the moment it gets used in another country or calendar change: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var month = d.getMonth();
var day = d.getDate();
var c = new Date(year + 2, month, day + 30)

var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0] = "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";

var n = weekday[c.getDay()];

document.write(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your looking for the `getDay` method of the `Date` object.
Take a look at the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

```js
const now = new Date();
console.log("now:", now.toISOString())

// 2 years and 30 days later from now
const later = new Date(now.getFullYear() + 2, now.getMonth(), now.getDate() + 30);
console.log("later:", later.toISOString())

const days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thr", "Fri", "Sat"];
console.log(later.getDay(), days[later.getDay()])
```

And an important note on that method:

> Date.prototype.getDay()
>
> Returns the day of the week (0-6) for the
> specified date **according to local time**.

Emphasis mine. So if this is running on the client, the day of week will be in their local time, not UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var weekday =
 ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]

var someDate = new Date();
var numberOfDaysToAdd = 30;
var numberOfyearsToAdd = 2;

someDate.setDate(someDate.getFullYear() + numberOfyearsToAdd + 
                 someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd); 

console.log(weekday[someDate.getDay()]);
```